# Clean multi line Word inserted breaks

Tags: php

I am trying to clean up Word codes that I get in my textarea input fields when clients paste in content from Word. My function works well except on blocks of code that are on two lines. For example

```
 <p><br />
</p>
```

I tried, letting my text entry in an array go over two lines, but it doesn't work.

```
    $badWordCodes2=array("<p></p>","<p>&nbsp;</p>","&nbsp;","<p ><br />
</p>");
$copy=str_replace($badWordCodes2,"",$copy);
```

My complete function is:

```
 function cleanWord($copy){
$badWordCodes=array("<o:p></o:p>","<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>","<p class=\"MsoNormal\">&nbsp;</p>","class=\"MsoNormal\"","<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>");
$copy=str_replace($badWordCodes,"",$copy);
$badWordCodes2=array("<p></p>","<p>&nbsp;</p>","&nbsp;","<p ><br />
</p>");
$copy=str_replace($badWordCodes2,"",$copy);
return $copy;
}
```

I considered using substr_replace() with strpos, but if the `</p>` wasn't there, it could wipe out a lot of text. I need something that will delete the entire two lines of code:

```
  <p><br />
</p>
```

and nothing else.

Any ideas or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a set of allowbale tags, then maybe https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I tried strip_tags but even with a fairly long list of "acceptable" tags, it blew up the formatting on some messages. It's an Atomic Bomb. I'm looking for a rifle.